# Multiple UITableViewCells being affected by iterated button despite only one being pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a `TableView` set as an iteration of a custom cell class. Each cell (in both of the two sections) contains a few labels and a button. For the cells in the the second section, the button text is programmatically set to "Cancel" while those in the first section are set to something different. I have set the button (for cells whose `button.title` is equal to "Cancel") to grey out the label texts by reducing the alpha values as follows once the button is clicked as follows:

```
@IBAction func mainPageCancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if mainPageCancelButton.title(for: .normal) == "x"{ //1st section cell
            mainPageCancelButton.setTitle("y", for: .normal)
        } else if mainPageCancelButton.title(for: .normal) == "y"{//1st section cell
            mainPageCancelButton.setTitle("x", for: .normal)
        } else if mainPageCancelButton.title(for: .normal) == "Cancel"//2nd section cell {
            mainPageUnattendCancelButton.setTitle("Canceled", for: .normal)
            NameLabel.alpha = 0.3
            CreatorLabel.alpha = 0.3
            TypeLabel.alpha = 0.3
        }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this button should only grey out the labels (by lowering the alpha values) in the second section, where the button is set as "Cancel". Clicking on the button in anyone of these 2nd section cells does indeed lower the alpha values for that cell, but also randomly (I think its random...) greys out some of the labels for the first section cells as well, even though they shouldn't be affected by that action since they don't satisfy the `if Button.title(for: .normal) == "Cancel"` if statement. Their titles are x and y. Not sure why this is happening. I figured the rudimentary if statement, though simplistic, should ensure none of the 1st section labels are affected by the alpha value change since their `button.title` can never be "Cancel". Not sure why this is happening, especially since the second section cells are affected correctly; only the cells with the button pressed will be greyed.

Comment: Do your cells in both sections have the same reuseidentifier? Could it be that alpha values for recycled cells in section 1 are using values that were set in section 2 previously? Do you reset the alpha values to defaults when you create each cell?

Comment: @Magnas yes they have the same reuse identifier. They are the same cells, just have the labels set to different values depending on the section. How would I reset the alpha values?

Comment: @Magnas it turns out that the issue can be solved just by doing as you suggested. Setting the alpha values to a default of 1.0 for the cells in the first section.

Answer (score 0):

Are labels grayed out in other cells immediately when pressing a button? Or only after scrolling?

If it's happening after scrolling the issue may have to do with the fact that cells are reused. If that's the case you should make sure the state of the cells are reset to something sensible. A good place for this is by overriding `prepareForReuse()` in your cell class:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    nameLabel.alpha = 1
    creatorLabel.alpha = 1
    typeLabel.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: the greying out happens immediately after pressing the button

Comment: In that case I would check if the button has multiple targets. Use the button's allTargets property—there should be just one. Accidentally calling addTarget(_:action:for:) multiple times can cause the button to invoke the action on multiple targets when tapped.